# How to make a DB query results cache accessible on different APP initializations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am developing a command line application with Spring Boot, that does some processing on some heavy DB queries.

**The problem:** All queries are really time consuming (aprox 1 hour) due to the amount of relationships between tables.

**Where I am right now:** I have looked for ways of caching the query results, via `@Cacheable` for example. Although, this kind of caching makes it not reusable between different application starts. Whenever I shutdown the application due to some code changes, I lose that cache and have to re-do the query.

**What I am looking for:** A caching solution that makes those results, from heavy queries, re-usable across different application runs (maybe save the cache to a file, or something...). I know I can do this to-file caching myself, but I would rather use a more standard way of doing so. Any suggestions?

Comment: *All queries are really time consuming* - make sure that you have the proper indexes in place

Comment: The slowness of the queries come from some factors: The test DB of the company where I am working on does not have a lot of processing resources, and the gap between my starting point and target table is of about 7 joins. executing all queries by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered Ehcache as backing implementation for the Spring cache abstraction?
It can be configured to store the contents of the cache to disk, in which case the cache will survive a JVM restart.
References:
[ehCache Tiering Options - Disk Tier](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/tiering.html)
[Spring 5 Reference: Cache Abstraction - Configuring the Cache Storage - Ehcache-based Cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-store-configuration-ehcache)

Comment: I will take a look into it. Thank you!

Comment: Ivan, I have just tested an EhCache java configuration for spring boot, and it works (besides the persistence config that asks for an "enterprise" library version to work).

Comment: What persistence configuration require an enterprise library version? I managed to run a small example with caching to disk without being asked for an enterprise version. Also see this example in the ehcache GitHub repo: https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/0d9707020e9683af8d5e0bcf5ccc3ca4e6f5ea65/xml/src/test/resources/configs/disk-persistent-cache.xml

Comment: I have tried similar configurations on my example project, but got an error on the xml schema definition. Maybe I was using an old version of EhCache. I got asked by the enterprise version when trying to configure, via java config, the persistence with “LOCALRESTARTABLE".